# Socket option SO_BSP_STATE fails with WSAEFAULT

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, winsock

When using the function [`getsockopt(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-getsockopt) with the level `SOL_SOCKET` and option `SO_BSP_STATE`, I am receiving the WSA error code `WSAEFAULT`, which states the following:

> "*One of the `optval` or the `optlen` parameters is **not** a valid part of the user address space, or the `optlen` parameter is too small.*"

However, I was passing in a correctly sized, user-mode buffer:

```
/* ... */

HRESULT Result      = E_UNEXPECTED;
CSADDR_INFO Info    = { 0 };                // Placed on the stack.
int InfoSize        = sizeof (CSADDR_INFO); // The size of the input buffer to `getsockopt()`.

// Get the local address information from the raw `SOCKET`.
if (getsockopt (this->WsaSocket,
                SOL_SOCKET,
                SO_BSP_STATE,
                reinterpret_cast <char *> (&Info),
                &InfoSize) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    Result = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32 (WSAGetLastError ());
}
else
{
    Result = S_OK;
}

/* ... */
```

According to the socket option `SO_BSP_STATE` documentation [under the remarks section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-getsockopt#remarks) of the `getsockopt(...)` function, the return value is of type `CSADDR_INFO`. Furthermore, the Microsoft documentation page for the [SO_BSP_STATE socket option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/so-bsp-state), states the following requirements:
`optval`:

> "[...] This parameter should point to buffer equal to or larger than the size of a `CSADDR_INFO` structure."

`optlen`:

> "[...] This size must be equal to or larger than the size of a `CSADDR_INFO` structure."

After doing some research, I stumbled upon some test code from WineHQ that was passing in more memory than `sizeof(CSADDR_INFO)` when calling `getsockopt(...)` (see lines [1305](https://github.com/alexhenrie/wine/blob/7485bb44c6e59a50de9c700de73740648f465c5e/dlls/ws2_32/tests/sock.c#L1305) and [1641](https://github.com/alexhenrie/wine/blob/7485bb44c6e59a50de9c700de73740648f465c5e/dlls/ws2_32/tests/sock.c#L1641)):

```
union _csspace
{
    CSADDR_INFO cs;
    char space[128];
} csinfoA, csinfoB;
```

It also looks like the project ReacOS also references this same exact code ([see reference](https://doxygen.reactos.org/d4/d1a/sock_8c_source.html)). Even though this is a `union`, because `sizeof(CSADDR_INFO)` is always less than `128`, `csinfoA` will always be `128` bytes in size.

Therefore, this got me wondering how many bytes the socket option `SO_BSP_STATE` actually requires when calling `getsockopt(...)`. I created the following complete example (via Visual Studio 2019 / C++17) that illustrates that in fact `SO_BSP_STATE` requires a buffer more than `sizeof(CSADDR_INFO)`, which is in direct contrast to the Microsoft published documentation:

```
/**
 *  @note  This example was created and compiled in Visual Studio 2019.
 */
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

/**
 *  @brief  The number of bytes to increase the @ref CSADDR_INFO_PLUS_EXTRA_SPACE structure by.
 *  @note   Alignment and pointer size changes when compiling for Intel x86 versus Intel x64.
 *          The extra bytes required therefore vary.
 */
#if defined(_M_X64) || defined(__amd64__)
    #define EXTRA_SPACE (25u) // Required extra space when compiling for X64
#else
    #define EXTRA_SPACE (29u) // Required extra space when compiling for X86
#endif

/**
 *  @brief  A structure to add extra space passed the `CSADDR_INFO` structure.
 */
typedef struct _CSADDR_INFO_PLUS_EXTRA_SPACE
{
    /**
     *  @brief  The standard structure to store Windows Sockets address information.
     */
    CSADDR_INFO Info;

    /**
     *  @brief  A blob of extra space.
     */
    char Extra [EXTRA_SPACE];
} CSADDR_INFO_PLUS_EXTRA_SPACE;

/**
 *  @brief  The main entry function for this console application for demonstrating an issue with `SO_BSP_STATE`.
 */
int main (void)
{
    HRESULT Result                      = S_OK;     // The execution result of this console application.
    SOCKET RawSocket                    = { 0 };    // The raw WSA socket index variable the references the socket's memory.
    WSADATA WindowsSocketsApiDetails    = { 0 };    // The WSA implementation details about the current WSA DLL.
    CSADDR_INFO_PLUS_EXTRA_SPACE Info   = { 0 };    // The structure `CSADDR_INFO` plus an extra blob of memory.
    int InfoSize                        = sizeof (CSADDR_INFO_PLUS_EXTRA_SPACE);

    std::cout << "Main Entry!" << std::endl;

    // Request for the latest Windows Sockets API (WSA) (a.k.a. Winsock) DLL available on this system.
    if (WSAStartup (MAKEWORD(2,2),
                    &WindowsSocketsApiDetails) != 0)
    {
        Result = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32 (WSAGetLastError ());
    }

    // Create a blank TCP socket using IPv4.
    if ((RawSocket = WSASocketW (AF_INET,
                                 SOCK_STREAM,
                                 IPPROTO_TCP,
                                 nullptr,
                                 0,
                                 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        Result = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32 (WSAGetLastError ());
    }
    else
    {
        // Get the local address information from the raw `SOCKET`.
        if (getsockopt (RawSocket,
                        SOL_SOCKET,
                        SO_BSP_STATE,
                        reinterpret_cast <char *> (&Info),
                        &InfoSize) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            std::cout << "Failed obtained the socket's state information!" << std::endl;
            Result = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32 (WSAGetLastError ());
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Successfully obtained the socket's state information!" << std::endl;
            Result = S_OK;
        }
    }

    // Clean up the entire Windows Sockets API (WSA) environment and release the DLL resource.
    if (WSACleanup () != 0)
    {
        Result = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32 (WSAGetLastError ());
    }

    std::cout << "Exit Code: 0x" << std::hex << Result << std::endl;
    return Result;
}
```

(*If you change the `EXTRA_SPACE` define to equal `0` or `1`, then you will see the issue I am outlining.*)

Due to the default structure alignment and pointer size change when compiling for either X86 or X64 in Visual Studio 2019, the required extra space beyond the `CSADDR_INFO` structure can vary:

- Space required for X86: `sizeof(CSADDR_INFO) + 29`
- Space required for X64: `sizeof(CSADDR_INFO) + 25`

This is completely arbitrary as shown and if you don't add this arbitrary padding, then `getsockopt(...)` will fail. This makes me call into question if the data I am getting back is even correct. This looks like there might be a missing footnote in the published documentation, however, I very well could be misunderstanding something (*very likely this*).

**My Question(s):**

- What is tied to the buffer size that `SO_BSP_STATE` actually requires (i.e. a structure, etc.)? Because, it is clearly **not** `sizeof(CSADDR_INFO)` as documented.
- Is the Microsoft documentation incorrect ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/so-bsp-state))? If **not**, what issues are spotted in my above code example, if `EXTRA_SPACE` is set to `0`, in order for `getsockopt(...)` to be successful?

Comment: I ran into the same issue. How come we are the only ones with this problem??? (No other search results show up.)

Comment: @Bas Yeah, I agree with you. It is strange no one else raised this as a problem before. Maybe the few people actually using this API didn't have any issues. The accepted answer below is the correct resolution to my original question. I have confirmed on my end that this is correct. Although, I sadly never got around to fixing the documentation on Microsoft's documentation website (formally MSDN) to be more clear about this. Thanks for the bump - I will look into fixing the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's happening here is as follows:

1. `CSADDR_INFO` is defined like so:

```
typedef struct _CSADDR_INFO {
  SOCKET_ADDRESS LocalAddr;
  SOCKET_ADDRESS RemoteAddr;
  INT            iSocketType;
  INT            iProtocol;
} CSADDR_INFO;
```

Specifically, it contains two `SOCKET_ADDRESS` structures.

2. `SOCKET_ADDRESS` is defined like so:

```
typedef struct _SOCKET_ADDRESS {
  LPSOCKADDR lpSockaddr;
  INT        iSockaddrLength;
} SOCKET_ADDRESS;
```

3. The `lpSockaddr` of the `SOCKET_ADDRESS` structure is a *pointer* to a `SOCK_ADDR` structure, and the length of *that* varies by address family (ipv4 vs ipv6, for example).

It follows that `getsockopt`  needs somewhere to store these `SOCK_ADDR` structures and that's where your 'blob' of extra data comes in - they're in there, pointed to by the two `SOCKET_ADDRESS` structures.  It further follows that the worst-case scenario for the size of this extra data may be more than you are allowing, since, if they are ipv6 addresses, they will be longer than if they are ipv4 addressses.

Of course, the documentation should spell all of this out, but, as is sometimes the case, the authors probably didn't understand how things work.  You might like to [raise a bug report](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/feedback).

Comment: Yeah, I saw that each `SOCKET_ADDRESS` have a pointer in them, but I did not know they were copying each `SOCKADDR` into the same buffer space and then just pointed to them (I thought maybe we it just pointed somewhere in the socket's allocated memory). I will definitely raise a bug to this and get this fixed. Thanks for point this out!

Comment: Please tread carefully.  This is guesswork on my behalf, but you can confirm it (or otherwise) by looking at the addresses in the `SOCKET_ADDRESS` structures returned by `getsockopt`.

Comment: Yeah, absolutely! I am about to verify this theory. I accepted your answer before doing this because I found some WineHQ source code [here](https://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-patches/2014-December/136048.html), which lends credence to your thought process. Granted, this is not official Windows 10 source code, but I think it's a good bet this is what is happening. I will reply back to this thread once I have confirmed on my end.